# How to make java response to my html selection list

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am working a jsp file with java+html. I want my selection list being able to change a variable **int k** in a part of java codes to `out.println` the different data sets for google pie chart which I am already done. By now, I merely know how to create a simple select list.
**What other information or techniques should I gather?**
Thanks in advance.

```
<select name="monthpick" id="monthpick">
    <option value="0">Jan16</option>
    <option value="1">Feb16</option>
    <option value="2">Mar16</option>
</select>
```

I want the the list can pass the value to **k** so that I can select what data set I want.

```
<%
String columnName = pchart.getColumnHeader(k);
String[][] pdata = pchart.getPieChartData(columnName, rowTitle);
for (int i=0;i<pdata.length;i++){
        out.println("[");
        for (int j=0;j<pdata[i].length;j++){    
            //...many out.println()

        }
    }
%>
```

Just for reference , the loop will out.print sth like below for pie chart:

```
['AA', 31578049.4], 
['BB', 8668926.34], 
['CC', 181917208.64], 
['GG', 164748309.85], 
['NN', 0], 
['PA', 0],
```

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it.

Both the select and the scriptlet code become source for rendering HTML sent to the browser on the back end.

You can, however, do it a couple of different ways.

Option 1. You can submit your selection to the server to get the pie chart data as a post or get in a form submit.  You can then receive the data and produce the output using JavaScript.  You can also do it with an ajax call to retrieve the pie chart data and then use JavaScript to render the pie chart data.

Option 2.
You can send a request from the form which will go to the back end.  If the variable k is set then you can render the value.

Basically you could send your query like so

http://myhost/some/mypage.jsp?colorpick=Jan16 . Or do a regular form submit

on mypage.jsp

```
<%

if (request.getParameter("colorpick") != null) {
   String k = (String)request.getParameter("colorpick");
   String columnName = pchart.getColumnHeader(k);
   String[][] pdata = pchart.getPieChartData(columnName, rowTitle);
   for (int i=0;i<pdata.length;i++){
        out.println("[");
        for (int j=0;j<pdata[i].length;j++){    
            //...many out.println()

        }
    }
}


%>
```

Option 3. You can preload the data in a javascript block and then through JavaScript access the data.  That wouldn't be optimal but it would work. I say it would not be optimal because there would be a lot of data to store in JavaScript variables.

I think the key solution would be to use JavaScript to handle that manipulation.  Your browser can't execute Java code within the browser.  It executes it prior to sending the request to the client.  So your JavaCode is no good client side.

I hope this helps.

Comment: hello, FernandoZ, What if I got a new idea which is I used loop to generate all pie charts I needed(says 10). Then, I create selection list and js function to control the `style=display:none` to control which chart I want to display, does it sound good?

Comment: Yes... you could do that.